# Google Cloud Function - could not handle the request

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I deployed 2 functions.

A: https://us-central1-wespace-project.cloudfunctions.net/dev3/genID/0013

B: https://asia-northeast1-wespace-project.cloudfunctions.net/dev/genID/0013

Both functions do the same thing, create a unique id. But, function "B" will be crashed after running around 30 seconds.

I had created a "cronjob" to make a call to function "B" every minute.  (To make it warm)

First day it went smooth, my cronjob logged the result as I expect. But, later the function went down, up, down, up for any minute the cronjob call.

Function "A" still working as I expect. You can run the function any times.

Function "B", you may run it work or fail. If you get return "500: could not handle the request", just call it again (refresh). The function will be restarted and then it works. You may try call it again. It still be working. After that for 30-35 seconds, the function will be crashed.

I'm not sure what happened. Please help.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions having connection error on new deployments.

https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Functions/18046